# Using an int as a case in an enum

Tags: swift, enums, int

I'm working with some basic Swift operations. Using a slider, I want to dictate a corresponding label. As the slider uses an `int` to represent the position, I was going to use an enum to convert.

```
enum Temperature: Int {
   case 0 = "Zero"
   case 1 = "One"
   case 2 = "Two"
   case 3 = "Three"
}
```

And I would like to call it like this:

```
variable = Temperature.0
```

Any help would be ideal. Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: Document here :- http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/224/enums#t=201607271236068847981

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. It's by design. A case in enum in swift must have a name (String) but not Int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use an array:

```
let temperatures = ["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three"]

let one = temeratures[1]
```

Or a tuple:

```
let temperatures = ("Zero", "One", "Two", "Three")

let one = temperatures.1
```

Whereas you cannot use runtime values (non-literals) in the latter

Answer (score 4):

Raw values of an enum is put on the right side of the `=`. In your enum `Temperature`, the raw value type is `Int`, so you should probably do it this way:

```
enum Temperature: Int {
    case Zero = 0, One, Two, Three
}
```

I didn't write the raw values for the other cases because they can be inferred.

Now you can access a case like this:

```
Temperature.One
```

"But I want to access it using integer literals!" you cried.

Unfortunately, this is impossible in Swift. The closest thing you can get is this:

```
enum Temperature: Int {
    case _0 = 0, _1, _2, _3
}
```

---

And you can initialize your enum using the initializer:

```
Temperature(rawValue: 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Best option I would say that you use a dictionary:

```
let Temperatures:[Int: String] = [0: "zero", 1:"one"]
```

Then you can access it with the slider value. Be aware of when accessing values not in dictionary -> Check for nil.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way

```
enum CompassPoint : Int {
      case north = 0
      case south = 1
      case east = 2
      case west = 3 
 }

func checkPoint(compass : CompassPoint) -> String {

   switch compass {
       case .east:
           return "Batsman"
       case .south:
           return "Bowler"
       case .north:
           return "Wicket Keeper"
       case .west:
           return "All Rounder"
   }}
```

`print(checkPoint(compass: CompassPoint(rawValue: 3)!))`

Answer (score 1):

I found your question while seeking the same answer, but I solved it myself with the CaseIterable and RawRepresentable Protocols. Going back to the OP's example:

```
enum Temperatures: String, CaseIterable, RawRepresentable {
    case zero
    case one
    case two
    case three
}
```

You can then implicitly reference the cases (as Strings) as indexes of the enum like so:

```
let x = Temperatures.allCases[0].rawValue
// x = "zero"
let y = Temperatures.allCases[2].rawValue
// y = "two"
```

For capitalization, you can either define the cases as capitals (which is not considered proper code)...

```
//...
case Zero
case One
//...
```

or explicitly define the RawRepresentable String values for each case:

```
//...
case zero = "Zero"
case one = "One"
//...
```

or go back to my first example and simply .capitalized the implict String values:

```
//...
case zero
case one
//...

let x = Temperatures.allCases[0].rawValue.capitalized
// x = "Zero"
```

These Protocols have come in SO handy for me! Great for iterating Enums:

```
for temp in Temperatures.allCases {
print(temp.rawValue.capitalized)
}

/* Output
Zero
One
Two
Three
*/
```

I was really surprised that Enum cases weren't automatically implicitly assigned Int values under the hood (like C#), but the CaseIterable Protocol makes them almost as easily referenced as such.

Answer (score 0):

Use tuple, enum is not for this purpose.

```
let temperature = ("Zero", "One", "Two", "Three")
let zero = temperature.0
```